# Algorithm to analyse and predict

Tags: algorithms, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I'm having a set of data's, say

```
Question,
Question's Main Category,Main Category followers,
Question's Related Categories,Each Related Categories followers,
Whether it got answer in 24hrs [Yes/No]
```

Now, I need to analyse a database with thousands of sets of data's like given above and predict whether the new given question(with all details like main category,followers...etc) will get answer in 24hrs or not ?

I have no idea which algorithm will be more suitable to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Isn't it a question for Cross Validated? ([Stats SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/))? Yes, learning more about statistical models is very much recommended.

Comment: As a hint: consider looking for probit regression on the search engines.